# chrome double click selection characters

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, selection

In chrome, double clicking by default selects characters with certain delimiters.  For example, a_b will be entirely selected but a-b won't be entirely selected.  Is there a way to add the minus/hyphen also as a selection character (and remove it from the delimiters list)?

Comment: I wish this had an answer, even if "that's not possible" but I hope it is.